# Cannot start Jira 8.10 with the atlassian SDK

Tags: maven, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

So I installed the atlassian SDK. My `atlas-version` is

```
ATLAS Version: 8.2.2
ATLAS Home: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2
ATLAS Scripts: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/bin
ATLAS Maven Home: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/apache-maven-3.5.4
AMPS Version: 8.1.0
--------
Executing: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn --version -gs /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T18:33:14Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/apache-maven-3.5.4
Java version: 1.8.0_272, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-51-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

If I `atlas-run-standalone --product jira --version 7.6.3`, for example, everything works as it should.

However, if I

```
atlas-run-standalone --product jira --version 8.10
```

then

```
Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:amps-maven-plugin:8.1.0:run-standalone (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: Could not find artifact com.atlassian.jira.plugins:jira-plugin-test-resources:zip:8.10 in atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public)
```

Relevant logs:

```
Downloaded from atlassian-public: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.0/maven-shared-utils-3.2.0.jar (165 kB at 28 kB/s)
Downloaded from atlassian-public: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/classworlds/classworlds/1.1/classworlds-1.1.jar (38 kB at 6.3 kB/s)
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.atlassian.jira.plugins:jira-plugin-test-resources:8.10:zip
Downloading from atlassian-public: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.pom
Downloading from atlassian-plugin-sdk: file:///usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/repository/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.jira.plugins:jira-plugin-test-resources:zip:8.10 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from atlassian-public: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.zip
Downloading from atlassian-plugin-sdk: file:///usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.2/repository/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.zip
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/atlassian/jira/plugins/jira-plugin-test-resources/8.10/jira-plugin-test-resources-8.10.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I start jira 8.10 using the sdk?

EDIT: [Full logs](https://workupload.com/file/ufpxY3heuWH)

Comment: this log doesn't say too much. any chance you can share the full log?

Comment: @YuriG. Added them, but I'm afraid they're not really providing any more information.

Answer (score 0):

The error at the end of your full log says

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:amps-maven-plugin:8.1.0:run-standalone (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: Could not find artifact com.atlassian.jira.plugins:jira-plugin-test-resources:zip:8.10 in atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public)
```

Searching for the [`ira-plugin-test-resources`](https://packages.atlassian.com/webapp/#/search/package/eyJzZWFyY2giOiJnYXZjIiwiYXJ0aWZhY3RJRCI6ImppcmEtcGx1Z2luLXRlc3QtcmVzb3VyY2VzIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjgiLCJzZWxlY3RlZFBhY2thZ2VUeXBlIjp7ImlkIjoiZ2F2YyIsImRpc3BsYXlOYW1lIjoiTWF2ZW4gR0FWQyIsImljb24iOiJwb20ifX0=) in atlassian's artifactory shows that there is no such version.

You should search the atalssain's artifactory to figure out what are available versions

**Update:**
Seems like at the moment, the latest available JIRA version for the sdk is 8.8.0-m0003

Comment: There's no plugin. I'm running `atlas-run-standalone`. In a container that has just the jdk and the atlassian sdk in it.

Comment: In the full logs at the beginning: `Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1`

Comment: ok, so look for the atlassian's documentation how to pass the test resources version and pass the correct version

Comment: Passing test resources version has been deprecated, data version defaults to RELEASE.
What IS the correct version?

Comment: search their artifactory. seems like the latest available version for the sdk is 8.8.0-m0003

Comment: Well, I can put it in `--test-version` and it gets ignored, since it's deprecated. If I feed it to  `--data-version`, the sdk will still fail because this time " The POM for com.atlassian.jira:atlassian-jira-webapp:war:8.10 is missing, no dependency information available". Which I'm not sure what to feed next.

Comment: That's why I say `seems like the latest available version for the sdk is 8.8.0-m0003 `

Comment: Oh, so you meant the SDK doesn't support ANY version beyond 8.8? Atlassian is now on Jira `8.13` (supposedly their LTS), but they don't support developing plugins for higher than `8.8`? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: But thanks, guess I can stop trying if that's the case...

Comment: you can post a question in atlassian community's portal https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/qa-p/jira-questions

Comment: I have, But they're a community forum for a niche developer audience. I don't expect any answer before the end of the year. Possibly not before the end of the next.

Comment: Hm ... there are some 8.13 artifacts lying around in the artifactory, if you're lucky in filtering. (no 8.10, though). Let's see if one of them works...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full version number: 8.10.0